# Show order button regardless of stock

Tags: magento2, stock

My Magento installation is configured to show products regardless of stock (`System -> Configuration -> Inventory` -> `Display Out of Stock Products`).

Is it also possible to make products order-able regardless of stock? Basically completely ignoring stock.

Answer (score 0):

`System -> Configuration -> Inventory -> Manage Stock` = No

You can also set this per product under the Inventory section while editing a product.